# Python}Google Colab| Unable to load in a dataframe either pickle files or csv files from drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am able to  see the files , however when i use the same path i am unable to load the file i..e pickle files or csv files from google drive through colab.

Code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!ls "/content/drive/My Drive/April_2023/Source_pickle_files"
```

When i execute the above code line i see list of pickle files in this path

```
Example=joblib.load("./content/drive/My Drive/April_2023/Source_pickle_files/example.pkl")
```

Using the same path when trying to load the pickle file it says path/dir doesnt exist/ (same for excel files too)

```
Example = pd.read_excel('./content/drive/My Drive/April_2023/Sourcefiles_Nov 2020-Apr 
2023/Example.xlsx', sheet_name='Information')
```

Using the same path when trying to load the csv file it says path/dir doesnt exist/

Comment: typo? should be `/content` not `./content`

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because of the dot (`.`). By putting this one at the start of your both file paths, Python tries to look for them in the current working directory (*which is /content in your case*), hence the error.

Try this :

```
Example = joblib.load("/content/drive/My Drive/April_2023/Source_pickle_files/example.pkl")

Example = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/April_2023/Sourcefiles_Nov 2020-Apr 
2023/Example.xlsx', sheet_name='Information')
```

Comment: Yes because of . .It worked now. Thank you